# clearing keychain for UIAutomation tests

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am writing UIAutomation tests to test the UI of our iPhone App.

Since some data is stored in Keychain on the first run of the application, I would like to reset the keychain when starting my UIAutomation test.

Is there any way this can be done using UIAutomation?

Thanks in advance,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

I drive UIAutomation through a custom bash script that uses Automator to reset the simulator before running my tests.  That way, everything is a clean slate.